# Credit card name format?

Tags: payment-gateway, credit-card

We are implementing payment solution, and question has emerged as to where you can find information about standards that reglament the character usage in the name of the card. At the moment we are stripping [^a-zA-Z0-9.-] out of the user input, but is that correct?

Could not find info. So if you have idea, please share.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004532/credit-card-validation-can-card-name-contain-non-ascii-characters/2005287#2005287

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It usually depends on the merchant you use. If you are using Realex Payments, they have a reg-epx pattern in their developer's documentation on this field.